# sidebar height is upto something is written

Tags: php, html, css

I am not able to make the sidebar all the way touch to the footer earlier it was going to the bottom but i made few changes for hours and suddenly when i checked it sidebar color only shows till it displays some links.

### css:

```
    *{margin:0; padding:0;}
html{ width:1024px; height:100%; margin: 0 auto; }
body{ width:100%;height:100%;
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
    font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px;
    background: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
#main { height:auto; min-height:100%; }
/* header */
#header{
    background-color:#c42000;
    height:75px; margin:0; padding:0;
     border:0 solid;
}
#header h1{
    line-height:15px; padding:1em;
}
#header h1 a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#header h1 a:hover {
    color:#cda154;
}
/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    color:#d3d3d3;
    height:45px;
    background:#262525;
    float:top;
}
#navigation .subjects {
 background: #262525;
 float: left;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
 border-bottom: none;
}

#navigation .subjects li a, #navigation .subjects li {
 float: left;
}

#navigation .subjects li {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation .subjects li a {
 padding: 1em 2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background: #292929;

 border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
 border-left: 1px solid #292929;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
 border-top: 1px solid #545454;
}

#navigation .subjects li a:hover {
 background: #302f2f; color:#16a9e0;
}


/* Submenu */

#navigation .subjects li ul {
 display: none;
 pos

ition: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 100%;
     padding: 0; margin: 0;
    }

    #navigation .subjects li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
    }

    #navigation .subjects li ul li, #navigation.subjects li ul li a {
     float: none;
    }

    #navigation .subjects li ul li {
     _display: inline; /* for IE6 */
    }

    #navigation .subjects li ul li a {
     width: 150px;
     display: block;
    }

    /* Sidebar */
    #sidebar {
        float:right;
        width: 150px; height: 100%;
        margin: 0; padding: 0 2em;
        color: #D4E6F4; background: #16aae2;
    }
    #sidebar a { color: #D4E6F4; text-decoration: none; }
    #sidebar a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; }

    /* footer */
    #footer {
        clear: both; position: relative;
        height: 2em; margin: 0; padding: 1em; margin-top: -3em; z-index:10;
        text-align: center;
        background: #000000; color: #D4E6F4;
    }

    /* page */
    #page {
        display:table-cell;
        float:left;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 2em;
    }
    h2 {    color:#c42000; }

    div.message,div.error {
        color: #8D0D19; font-weight:bold;
        margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;
    }

    div.images {
        width:92;height:92; float:left; padding: 0 10px 0; display:block;
    }
    div.images a{ text-decoration:none;}
```

### php:

```
    <?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>

<?php find_selected_page(); ?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="navigation">
        <?php echo navigation($current_subject, $current_page); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
        <?php echo message(); ?>

        <?php if(isset($current_subject)) {?>
            <h2>Manage Subject</h2>
            Menu name: <?php echo htmlentities($current_subject["menu_name"]); ?><br />
            Position: <?php echo $current_subject["position"]; ?><br />
            Visible: <?php echo $current_subject["visible"] == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?><br /><br />

            <a href="edit_subject.php?subject=<?php echo urlencode($current_subject["id"]); ?>
            ">Edit Subject</a>
            <div style="margin-top: 2em; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
                <h2>Pages in this subject:</h2>
                    <?php 
                        $subject_pages = find_pages_for_subject($current_subject["id"]);
                        while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_pages)) {

                            $safe_page_id = urlencode($page["id"]);
                            echo "<a href=\"manage_content.php?page={$safe_page_id}\">";
                            echo htmlentities($page["menu_name"]);
                            echo "</a><br />";
                        }
                    ?>
                <br />
                <a href="new_page.php?subject=<?php echo urlencode($current_subject["id"]); ?>">+ Add a new page to this subject  </a>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($current_page) {?>
            <h2>Manage Page</h2>
            <?php ?>
            Page Name: <?php echo htmlentities($current_page["menu_name"]); ?><br />
            Position: <?php echo $current_page["position"]; ?><br />
            Visible: <?php echo $current_page["visible"] == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="edit_page.php?page=<?php echo urlencode($current_page["id"])?>">Edit Page</a><br /><br />
            <?php echo display_image_by_id(); ?>
        <?php }else { ?>
        Please Select a Subject or Page.
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="admin.php">&laquo; Main Menu</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="new_subject.php">+ Add a subject</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Could you copy the generated HTML instead of the PHP? Or maybe create a jsfiddle with the significant code?

Comment: there is no javascript inside it. Basically a php file generates a html file when run on server so... i was not able to add html src code. i am new to stackoverflow